# Create a yaml flow collection using PyYAML in Python

Tags: python, syntax, pyyaml, flask-apispec

I'm attempting to reproduce this YAML variable using PyYAML's dump:

```
x-google-backend:
  address: https://www.google.com
  path_translation: [ APPEND_PATH_TO_ADDRESS ]
```

Specifically the `path_translation: [ APPEND_PATH_TO_ADDRESS ]` is what I can't produce.

It's meant to take a python object and turn it into valid yaml. The trouble is I can only ever get

```
x-google-backend:
  address: https://www.google.com
  path_translation: '[ APPEND_PATH_TO_ADDRESS ]'
```

or

```
x-google-backend:
  address: https://www.google.com
  path_translation:
  - APPEND_PATH_TO_ADDRESS
```

From [PyYAML's own documentation](https://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation) it looks like what I'm trying to do is called a "flow collection". But when I tried their recommended syntax I just got the above result with the hyphen representing a list item.

Specifically I'm doing it inside a dictionary:

```
dict({"path_translation": [ "APPEND_PATH_TO_ADDRESS" ]}, address="https://www.google.com")
```

Any ideas about how to produce this correctly would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is the code needed to reproduce? By default, pyyaml will use the flow representation for collections that don't contain any nested collections according to [this](https://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation).

Comment: pyyaml `dump` is being called by apispec `to_yaml()`, which sets the Dumper as `dumper.represent_mapping("tag:yaml.org,2002:map", instance.items())`

Comment: I wasn't clear, apologies: please edit your question so it contains a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).